# Dummy Variables on training and testing set resulting in different size dataframe output

Tags: python, pandas

I am encoding my dataframes (training & testing) with onehot using `pd.get_dummies()`. However, both dataframes are rather large and I noticed that it outputs different column sizes. 271 vs 290. This is due to certain qualitative variables having values in one dataframe vs. not in the other.

Is there a command I can use with `pd.get_dummies` to make sure that I am getting an empty column with 0's when these variables are present in the other dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the dataframe , and would like to transform object to dummies variable, dot not split it before using  `get_dummies`

```
 df = pd.get_dummies(df)
 train = df[cond]
 test = df.drop(train.index)
```

---

To fix your code

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.concat([train , test]))
train = df[df.index.isin(train.index)]
test = df.drop(train.index)
```

Comment: Had to make a couple of modifications but the idea worked. Thanks for the help. The csv's came split originally and that was an excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your safest bet, when possible, is to convert your column to a categorical  datatype that includes all possible values before using `get_dummies`.  This is especially useful if your training data changes frequently (streaming/frequently updated) and you want maximal compatibility:

```
x_values = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
x_type = pd.Categorical(values=x_values)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[1,2,3]))
```

dummies that don't know about possible values "d", "e":

```
x_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.x)

   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

dummies that are aware "d", "e" exist, even if not represented in present data:

```
df["x"] = df["x"].astype(x_cat)
x_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.x)

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  0  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  0
2  0  0  1  0  0
```